# NSDate nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options: return a wrong day

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I've to get last Sunday. I've tried with this code

```
+ (NSDate *)lastSunday {
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSCalendarOptions opt = NSCalendarSearchBackwards | NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits;

    return [gregorian nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date] matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday value:1 options:opt];
}
```

but returns me a Saturday instead Sunday. Instead, if I pass 2 to `value` parameter I get a Sunday, but I want understand the reason why I have to pass 2 (i.e. 2 represent Monday).

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: That's not a time zone.

Comment: If you are looking at the returned data in the debugger or console, you will be seeing midnight Sunday in your local timezone represented in UTC (+0000). Even if your local time zone is London you will be off by 1 hour due to summer time.  Try `NSLog(@"%@",[[self lastSunday] descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);`